# Android use recursive method to find and colorize found texts

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to use recursive method to find tags on string, remove it and then colorize found text(s). but my code couldn't return correct string as removed all tags with correct position after remove tags from string for colorize them

my recursive method work fine, but after return string i have problem, i have string with last tagged items!!

```
String str     = "11111111<mft:A>2222222</mft:A>1111111<mft:S>33333333</mft:S> <mft:A>99999</mft:A><mft:S>v44444444/mft:S><mft:R>555555</mft:R><mft:S>6666666</mft:S><mft:A>7777777</mft:A>111111";


String nonTags = extractAyehTags(str);
//result is: 1111111122222221111111<mft:S>33333333</mft:S> <mft:A>99999</mft:A><mft:S>v44444444/mft:S><mft:R>555555</mft:R><mft:S>6666666</mft:S><mft:A>7777777</mft:A>111111

Spannable WordToSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder(nonTags);

for (int p = 0; p < ayeHaPositions.size(); p++) {
    WordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), ayeHaPositions.get(p).getStart(), ayeHaPositions.get(p).getEnd(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}

welcome_message.setText(WordToSpan);
```

**my recursive method for remove tag and get found text positions**

```
private String extractAyehTags(String str) {
    String  nonTags    = str;
    Pattern mftA_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<mft:A>(.+?)</mft:A>");

    Matcher matcher = mftA_REGEX.matcher(str);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        String found = matcher.group(1);

        int start = str.indexOf(found.trim());

        ayeHaPositions.add(new AyehaTagsInformation(start - ("<mft:A>".length()), (start + found.length()) - ("</mft:A>".length()), found));
        nonTags = str.replace("<mft:A>" + matcher.group(1) + "</mft:A>", matcher.group(1));

        extractAyehTags(nonTags);
    }
    return nonTags;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

problem resolved after change recursive method:

```
private String extractAyehTags(String str) {
    nonTags = str;
    Pattern mftA_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<mft:A>(.+?)</mft:A>");

    Matcher matcher = mftA_REGEX.matcher(str);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        String found = matcher.group(1);

        int start = str.indexOf(found);

        ayeHaPositions.add(new AyehaTagsInformation(start - ("<mft:A>".length()), (start + found.length()+1) - ("</mft:A>".length()), found));
        nonTags = str.replace("<mft:A>" + matcher.group(1) + "</mft:A>", matcher.group(1));

        return extractAyehTags(nonTags);
    }
    return nonTags;
}
```

problem was this line:

```
extractAyehTags(nonTags);
```

i change it to:

```
return extractAyehTags(nonTags);
```